# Need help splicing string objects in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, string-formatting

I'm kinda new to Python, and building a card game. This question may be easy for a lot of people.

```
dealerCom = []

for subset in combinations(dealer_deck, 4) :
    dealerCom.append(str(dealer_card) + str(subset))

for hands in dealerCom :
    hands.replace(',', '')

print(dealerCom[1819])
print(dealerCom[1819].replace(',', '') )
```

First print statement returns KC ( 9D ,  5H ,  AH ,  TD )
Second print statement properly returns KC ( 9D   5H   AH   TD )

Trying to format out using the second for loop, however nothing inside it seems to work. The second print statement does however format somehow.

1. dealer_card is a object list [val= KC]
2. dealer_deck is a object list that we are finding combinations of [val= TS  9S  8C  5D  AC  JH  7D  QC  KH  6S  JD  2S  9D  5H  AH  TD]
3. Objective is to copy dealerCom list into a .txt file eventually using AB CD EF GH single space formatting, data only on 1820 individual lines
4. The str() conversion might seem weird, I was debugging a lot and that's the only thing that helped me actually print dealerCom[1819]

Answer (score 2):

the problem in the `for` loop is the `replace()`. `replace()` **does not** change the string it is called on, but returns a copy of this string with the desired changes.
change your code to look like this:

```
for index in range(len(dealerCom)):
    dealerCom[index] = dealerCom[index].replace(',', '')
```

Comment: Oh thanks alot, I just replaced it and it works fine now. Also thanks for taking the time out of your day. Spent two hours+ searching. Wish I could upvote but my rep is low

Comment: @jon_woot my pleasure. A little tip to help you next time: open your IDLE and then press F1. it will take you to a very detailed python documentation